# Have apache return 403 for everything that isn't a virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a Debian-style Apache setup (`sites-available`, `sites-enabled`) with several virtual hosts defined. I have multiple `A` records pointing to this machine's single IP address. I'd like to return a 403 status for every request to a host that isn't specified as a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` my site configuration files.

I know about [`_default_`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#default) but this won't work because it's a catch-all for IPs, and all of the requests are to the same IP.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html):

> If no matching vhost could be found the request is served from the first vhost with a matching port number that is on the list for the IP to which the client connected (as already mentioned before).

So all we need to do is make sure the first virtual host loaded denies all requests. To do this (with a Debian-style setup), create a new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with a filename that comes first alphabetically among all your sites. There is a default file called `000-default.conf` which works well for this purpose. Put the following directives in this file.

Since a `ServerName` should [always be set](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html), set it to the IP address of your machine.

```
ServerName <your ip address>
```

Set the document root to any folder. Although we will be denying access to this folder, it would be safest if it was an empty folder, in case something gets misconfigured later on.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Deny access to this folder.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

So now `000-default` will deny all requests, and it is the first virtual host loaded, so any hosts not matching a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` will default to it.

Enable this site with `a2ensite 000-default` and reload your configuration with `service apache2 reload` and you're good to go.